# Most efficient way of cleaning up files after a test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have written some test cases which test a function I have written. The function is to simply count the number of files in a particular directory. Eventually I will have another function which will behave in a certain way depending how many files are in each directory. In this case I am working with two directories. This is my function:
**dir_handler.py**

```
from pathlib import Path

def count_files_in_dir(dirpath):
    assert(dirpath.is_dir())
    file_list = []
    for file in dirpath.iterdir():
        if file.is_file():
            file_list.append(file)
    return len(file_list)
```

And here are my test cases:
**test_dir_handler.py**

```
from imports import *
import os
from main.dir_handler import count_files_in_dir


class DirHandlerTests(unittest.TestCase):

def test_return_count_of_zero_when_no_file_exists_in_input_dir(self):
    self.assertEqual(0, count_files_in_dir(INPUT_FILE_PATH))

def test_return_count_of_zero_when_no_file_exists_in_output_dir(self):
    self.assertEqual(0, count_files_in_dir(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH))

def test_return_count_of_one_when_one_file_exists_in_input_dir(self):
    with open(str(INPUT_FILE_PATH)+ "/"+"input.csv", "w") as file:
        self.assertEqual(1, count_files_in_dir(INPUT_FILE_PATH))

def test_return_count_of_one_when_one_file_exists_in_output_dir(self):
    with open(str(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)+ "/"+"output.csv", "w") as file:
        self.assertEqual(1, count_files_in_dir(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH))

def test_return_count_of_two_when_two_files_exists_in_output_dir(self):
    with open(str(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)+ "/"+"output.csv", "w") as file:
        with open(str(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)+ "/"+"output2.csv", "w") as file:
            self.assertEqual(2, count_files_in_dir(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH))

#clearing up testing files at the end of test
def tearDown(self):
    try:
        os.remove(str(INPUT_FILE_PATH)+ "/"+"input.csv")
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        pass
    try:
        os.remove(str(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)+ "/"+"output.csv")
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        pass

    try:
        os.remove(str(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)+ "/"+"output2.csv")
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see I am having to remove "input2.csv" and "output2.csv" individually which is not very effecient. Both INPUT_FILE_PATH and OUTPUT_FILE_PATH are under the same directory "files". All tests pass but I would like recommendations on the best way of cleaning INPUT_FILE_PATH and OUTPUT_FILE_PATH directories at the end of my tests. Thank you

**EDIT:**
Using @rockport's suggestion I have implemented a setUp / tearDown method. The code works as desired but is still quite messy. It clears up both output_file folder and input_file folder at the end of the test. Also I have implemented pathlib instead of os because I will be running and editing the code on mac and windows. Here are some changed to my code

```
def setUp(self):
        self.input_file = INPUT_FILE_PATH.joinpath("input.csv")
        self.output_file = OUTPUT_FILE_PATH.joinpath("output.csv")
        self.output_file2 = OUTPUT_FILE_PATH.joinpath("output2.csv")

def test_return_count_of_one_when_one_file_exists_in_output_dir(self):
    with self.output_file.open(mode='w') as file:
        self.assertEqual(1, count_files_in_dir(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH))

def test_return_count_of_two_when_two_files_exist_in_output_dir(self):
    with self.output_file.open(mode='w') as file:
            with self.output_file2.open(mode='w') as file:
                self.assertEqual(2, count_files_in_dir(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH))

def tearDown(self):
    for file in INPUT_FILE_PATH.iterdir():
        try:
            file.unlink()
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            pass
    for file in OUTPUT_FILE_PATH.iterdir():
        try:
            file.unlink()
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            pass
```

Comment: please fix indentations in your code. Do you have duplicate test functions here ? Looks like this.

Comment: @rocksportrocker removed deplicated test thanks

Comment: there is no need to open the files. you create file handler `file` which are not used later on.

Comment: I'm also a bit concerned where `OUTPUT_PATH` and `INPUT_PATH` are coming from. I'd create temporary folders in `setUp` instead.

Comment: This answer uses `pytest` for cleaning up temporary folders: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216769/how-to-delete-temporary-test-file

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) which will delete the whole directory, including any sub-directories and files in it. After that, you can recreate the directory with `os.mkdir` or `os.makedirs`. Here is an example:

```
import os
import shutil

shutil.rmtree(INPUT_FILE_PATH)
os.mkdir(INPUT_FILE_PATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to implement a `setUp` method, where you create your files in a temporary folder. Then you run your actual test(s) on this folder. Finally removal is not necessary.

Unittests should not rely on the environment, like files outside the test folder. This is why we use fixtures in testing.

---

The simplification you are asking for could be

```
def tearDown(self):

    for p, f in ((INPUT_FILE_PATH, "input.csv"),
                 (OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, "output.csv"),
                 (OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, "output2.csv")):
        try:
            os.remove(str(p) + "/" + f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
```

---

For your edit, why not just:

```
def test_return_count_of_one_when_one_file_exists_in_output_dir(self):
    self.assertEqual(1, count_files_in_dir(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to delete the whole tree, you could simply append the paths to a list and iterate over the list to remove every path in there

```
pathlist = []

def test_return_count_of_one_when_one_file_exists_in_output_dir(self):
    path = str(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) + "/output.csv"
    pathlist.append(path)
    with open(path, "w") as file:
        self.assertEqual(1, count_files_in_dir(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH))
```

And then:

```
for path in pathlist:
    try:
        os.remove(path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```